# how to merge two arrays values in one array php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I want to merge values of two array in to one array.

i am getting below output...

```
{
  "responseData": {    
    "result": [
      {
        "0": {
          "distance": "0"
        },
        "user_details": {
          "id": "13",
          "courier_address": "smartData Enterprises (I) Ltd., MIHAN, Nagpur, Nagpur, Maharashtra, India",
          "courier_lat": "21.0371687",
          "courier_long": "79.01362560000007"
        }
      },
      {
        "0": {
          "distance": "1.243540768279295"
        },
        "user_details": {
          "id": "14",
          "courier_address": "TCS, MIHAN, Nagpur, Telhara, Maharashtra, India",
          "courier_lat": "21.0540494",
          "courier_long": "79.02031090000003"
        }
      },
      {
        "0": {
          "distance": "1.578268494523629"
        },
        "user_details": {
          "id": "15",
          "courier_address": "Globallogic MIHAN SEZ Centre, MIHAN, Nagpur, Dahegaon, Maharashtra, India",
          "courier_lat": "21.0487625",
          "courier_long": "79.03471179999997"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my above data,the distance is coming in another arrays..
but i want to merge the values of distance is user_details array...

**Expected output**

```
{
  "responseData": {    
    "result": [
      {

        "user_details": {
          "id": "13",
          "courier_address": "smartData Enterprises (I) Ltd., MIHAN, Nagpur, Nagpur, Maharashtra, India",
          "courier_lat": "21.0371687",
          "courier_long": "79.01362560000007",
          "distance": "0"
        }
      },
      {

        "user_details": {
          "id": "14",
          "courier_address": "TCS, MIHAN, Nagpur, Telhara, Maharashtra, India",
          "courier_lat": "21.0540494",
          "courier_long": "79.02031090000003",
           "distance": "1.243540768279295"
        }
      },
      {

        "user_details": {
          "id": "15",
          "courier_address": "Globallogic MIHAN SEZ Centre, MIHAN, Nagpur, Dahegaon, Maharashtra, India",
          "courier_lat": "21.0487625",
          "courier_long": "79.03471179999997",
          "distance": "1.578268494523629"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Below is my code**

```
public function searchCourier(){      
    if($this->processRequest){
        $err = false; 
        if(empty($this->requestData['lat'])){
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Please enter latitude";
            $err = true;
        }
        if(empty($this->requestData['long'])){
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Please enter longitude";
            $err = true;
        }
        if(!$err){              
            $lat = $this->requestData['lat'];               
            $long = $this->requestData['long'];
            $this->loadModel('UserDetail'); 
            $data = $this->UserDetail->query("SELECT id,courier_address,courier_lat,courier_long,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( '$lat' ) ) * cos( radians( courier_lat ) ) * cos( radians( courier_long ) - radians( '$long' ) ) + sin( radians( '$lat' ) ) * sin( radians( courier_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
            FROM user_details HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");                
            $this->responceData['result'] = $data;
            $this->responceData['status'] = 1;
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Success";

        } else {
            $this->responceData['status'] = 0;
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Something Went Wrong.Please Try again";           
        }              
    }
}
```

**output of var_dump($data)**

```
 array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["user_details"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "13"
      ["courier_address"]=>
      string(73) "smartData Enterprises (I) Ltd., MIHAN, Nagpur, Nagpur, Maharashtra, India"
      ["courier_lat"]=>
      string(10) "21.0371687"
      ["courier_long"]=>
      string(17) "79.01362560000007"
    }
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["distance"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["user_details"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["courier_address"]=>
      string(47) "TCS, MIHAN, Nagpur, Telhara, Maharashtra, India"
      ["courier_lat"]=>
      string(10) "21.0540494"
      ["courier_long"]=>
      string(17) "79.02031090000003"
    }
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["distance"]=>
      string(17) "1.243540768279295"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["user_details"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "15"
      ["courier_address"]=>
      string(73) "Globallogic MIHAN SEZ Centre, MIHAN, Nagpur, Dahegaon, Maharashtra, India"
      ["courier_lat"]=>
      string(10) "21.0487625"
      ["courier_long"]=>
      string(17) "79.03471179999997"
    }
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["distance"]=>
      string(17) "1.578268494523629"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it's producing that array. You must be processing the result somewhere else after the `searchCourier()`-method, right?

Comment: Btw,, what's the point of `if (!$err)`? You are setting `$err = false;` in the line right above it. It will always contain false...

Comment: So `$this->UserDetail->query()` isn't a database call where you simple get a result back, but rather a Service that gives you the above array instead? Just trying to figure out where the `"user_details": { ...` gets added, for example.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the questions in my previous comment. Btw, is this all the code you have in the method or is this just a snippet, or even a rewrite for our benefit? It still looks like your data is being processed and structured somewhere else.

Comment: No..now i put complete code.....there...the flow is i am hitting this url from rest client http://172.10.1.3:8056/rajnikantb/parcelapp/api/Orders/searchCourier.json and provideing lat and long like {"lat":"21.0371687","long":"79.01362560000007"} in body...and this will provide me the above output...

Comment: $this->UserDetail->query is a database call...i am putting custom query inside this function and passing my $lat and &long inside this query....

Comment: This is not an array. It is a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. hope it helps

```
public function searchCourier(){      
    if($this->processRequest){
        $err = false; 
        if(empty($this->requestData['lat'])){
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Please enter latitude";
            $err = true;
        }
        if(empty($this->requestData['long'])){
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Please enter longitude";
            $err = true;
        }
        if(!$err){
            $lat = $this->requestData['lat'];
            $long = $this->requestData['long'];
            $this->loadModel('UserDetail'); 
            $data = $this->UserDetail->query("SELECT id,courier_address,courier_lat,courier_long,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( '$lat' ) ) * cos( radians( courier_lat ) ) * cos( radians( courier_long ) - radians( '$long' ) ) + sin( radians( '$lat' ) ) * sin( radians( courier_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
            FROM user_details HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");
            $this->responceData['result'] = array();
            // check if has data returned
            if($data) {
                foreach($data as $val) {
                    // try to var_dump or print_r the $val
                    // print_r($val);
                    // if $val data is = array(
                    //    'UserDetails' => array(
                    //        "id" => "15",
                    //       "courier_address" => "Globallogic MIHAN SEZ Centre, MIHAN, Nagpur, Dahegaon, Maharashtra, India",
                    //        "courier_lat" => "21.0487625",
                    //        "courier_long" => "79.03471179999997"
                    //    ),
                    //    0 => array(
                    //        "distance" => 123.3
                    //    )
                    // );

                    // store data as array
                    $this->responceData['result'][] = array(
                        'user_details' => array(
                            "id"=> $val['UserDetails']['id'],
                            "courier_address"=> $val['UserDetails']['courier_address'],
                            "courier_lat"=> $val['UserDetails']['courier_lat'],
                            "courier_long"=> $val['UserDetails']['courier_long'],
                            "distance"=> $val[0]['distance']
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            $this->responceData['status'] = 1;
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Success";
            $result = array(
              'responseData' => array(
                 'result' => $this->responceData['result']
              )
            );
            return json_encode($result);

        } else {
            $this->responceData['status'] = 0;
            $this->responceData['message'] = "Something Went Wrong.Please Try again";           
        }              
    }
}
```

Comment: i just edited my answer, oh you mean you want it as json format?.

Comment: No..my mean is your code also getting the distance in different array...not in same array....as i shown in my expected result ....i am putting the output in my question which i got from your code....

Comment: i mean you have tried this??

    $this->responceData['result'][] = array(
                        'user_details' => array(
                            "id"=> $val['UserDetails']['id'],
                            "courier_address"=> $val['UserDetails']['courier_address'],
                            "courier_lat"=> $val['UserDetails']['courier_lat'],
                            "courier_long"=> $val['UserDetails']['courier_long'],
                            "distance"=> $val[0]['distance']
                        )
                    );

Comment: and what's the result?

Comment: $data = $this->UserDetail->query("SELECT id,courier_address,courier_lat,courier_long,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( '$lat' ) ) * cos( radians( courier_lat ) ) * cos( radians( courier_long ) - radians( '$long' ) ) + sin( radians( '$lat' ) ) * sin( radians( courier_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
            FROM user_details HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");

or can i see the result if you var_dump($data); ?

Comment: just follow my answer and just change the [UserDetails] to [user_details]

Comment: when i change the [UserDetails] to [user_details]..this shows error...bcoz my model name is UserDetails....